# Google BigQuery: Rolling Count Distinct

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with is simply a list of dates and user IDs (not aggregated).

We define a metric called *active users* for a given date by counting the distinct number of IDs that appear in the previous 45 days.

I am trying to run a query in BigQuery that, for each day, returns the day plus the number of active users for that day (count distinct user from 45 days ago until today).

I have experimented with window functions, but can't figure out how to define a range based on the date values in a column. Instead, I believe the following query would work in a database like MySQL, but does not in BigQuery.

```
SELECT 
  day,
  (SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT visid) 
   FROM daily_users
   WHERE day BETWEEN DATE_ADD(t.day, -45, "DAY") AND t.day
   ) AS active_users
FROM daily_users AS t
GROUP BY 1
```

This doesn't work in BigQuery: "Subselect not allowed in SELECT clause."

How to do this in BigQuery?

Answer (score 2):

BigQuery [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#windowfunctions) claims that `count(distinct)` works as a window function.  However, that doesn't help you, because you are not looking for a traditional window frame.

One method would adds a record for each date after a visit:

```
select theday, count(distinct visid)
from (select date_add(u.day, n.n, "day") as theday, u.visid
      from daily_users u cross join
           (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all . . .
            select 45
           ) n
     ) u
group by theday;
```

Note:  there may be simpler ways to generate a series of 45 integers in BigQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Below should work with BigQuery

```
#legacySQL
SELECT day, active_users FROM (
  SELECT 
    day, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT id) 
      OVER (ORDER BY ts RANGE BETWEEN 45*24*3600 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS active_users
  FROM (
    SELECT day, id, TIMESTAMP_TO_SEC(TIMESTAMP(day)) AS ts 
    FROM daily_users
  )
) GROUP BY 1, 2 ORDER BY 1
```

Above assumes that `day` field is represented as '2016-01-10' format.
If it is not a case , you should adjust `TIMESTAMP_TO_SEC(TIMESTAMP(day))` in most inner select

Also please take a look at [COUNT(DISTINC)](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#countdistinct) specifics in BigQuery

> Update for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  day, 
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM UNNEST(active_users) id) AS active_users
FROM (
  SELECT 
    day, 
    ARRAY_AGG(id) 
      OVER (ORDER BY ts RANGE BETWEEN 3888000 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS active_users
  FROM (
    SELECT day, id,  UNIX_DATE(PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d', day)) * 24 * 3600 AS ts 
    FROM daily_users
  )
) 
GROUP BY 1, 2 
ORDER BY 1
```

You can test / play with it using below dummy sample

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH daily_users AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, '2016-01-10' AS day UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS id, '2016-01-10' AS day UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS id, '2016-01-11' AS day UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS id, '2016-01-11' AS day UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS id, '2016-01-12' AS day UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS id, '2016-01-12' AS day UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS id, '2016-01-12' AS day UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS id, '2016-01-13' AS day
)
SELECT 
  day, 
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM UNNEST(active_users) id) AS active_users
FROM (
  SELECT 
    day, 
    ARRAY_AGG(id) 
      OVER (ORDER BY ts RANGE BETWEEN 86400 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS active_users
  FROM (
    SELECT day, id,  UNIX_DATE(PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d', day)) * 24 * 3600 AS ts 
    FROM daily_users
  )
) 
GROUP BY 1, 2 
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: this query fails on standard sql: "Windows ORDER BY is not allowed if DISTINCT is specified". Do you have any ideas how to do something like this sliding window distinct count?

Comment: At a time of this answering - there was no yet Standard SQL available.  Beta availability of standard SQL was announced only in June 2016. Obviously this answer was provided for BigQuery Legacy SQL and it still DOES work for Legacy. I recommend you to post your question with your specific details - I or anyone else here will be glad to answer your question! promise!

Comment: @GeorgeHilios - see update for standard sql in above answer!

Comment: I actually did the exact same thing :) Funny to see we came up with the same workaround. This array can get very large when operating on big data sets, so I had to also add a few nested queries that trim it down further before aggregating. Very messy. I'm hoping Google can simplify this soon!

Comment: @GeorgeHilios - sure. consider voting up if it addressed question in your original comment:o)