# BigQuery distinct count in rolling date range, with partition on column

Tags: sql, database, count, google-bigquery, window-functions

I have a table of consisting of email, day (TIMESTAMP), id, and multiple other columns.

For each email entry, I would like to count the number of unique ids associated with that email in the preceding 3 days.

```
+-------------------+-------------------------+------------+----+
|       email       |           day           | other cols | id |
+-------------------+-------------------------+------------+----+
| user1@gmail.com   | 2020-06-21 16:31:00 UTC |        ... |  0 |
| user1@gmail.com   | 2020-06-22 14:54:00 UTC |        ... |  1 |
| user1@gmail.com   | 2020-06-23 08:23:00 UTC |        ... |  0 |
| user1@gmail.com   | 2020-06-24 13:51:00 UTC |        ... |  0 |
| user1@gmail.com   | 2020-06-25 09:54:00 UTC |        ... |  2 |
| user1@gmail.com   | 2020-06-25 12:25:00 UTC |        ... |  0 |
| user1@gmail.com   | 2020-06-26 15:21:00 UTC |        ... |  2 |
| user2@hotmail.com | 2020-06-21 12:23:00 UTC |        ... |  0 |
| user2@hotmail.com | 2020-06-21 16:54:00 UTC |        ... |  0 |
| user2@hotmail.com | 2020-06-22 08:23:00 UTC |        ... |  0 |
| user2@hotmail.com | 2020-06-22 12:13:00 UTC |        ... |  1 |
| user2@hotmail.com | 2020-06-24 09:32:00 UTC |        ... |  1 |
| user2@hotmail.com | 2020-06-25 05:45:00 UTC |        ... |  1 |
| user2@hotmail.com | 2020-06-26 12:32:00 UTC |        ... |  2 |
| user2@hotmail.com | 2020-06-27 19:53:00 UTC |        ... |  1 |
+-------------------+-------------------------+------------+----+
```

The additional column should look like this:

```
+-------------------+-------------------------+------------+----+-----------------------------+
|       email       |           day           | other cols | id | distinct ids in last 3 days |
+-------------------+-------------------------+------------+----+-----------------------------+
| user1@gmail.com   | 2020-06-21 16:31:00 UTC |        ... |  0 |                           1 |
| user1@gmail.com   | 2020-06-22 14:54:00 UTC |        ... |  1 |                           2 |
| user1@gmail.com   | 2020-06-23 08:23:00 UTC |        ... |  0 |                           2 |
| user1@gmail.com   | 2020-06-24 13:51:00 UTC |        ... |  0 |                           2 |
| user1@gmail.com   | 2020-06-25 09:54:00 UTC |        ... |  2 |                           3 |<- 3, because ids 0, 1 and 2 have been seen in previous 3 days
| user1@gmail.com   | 2020-06-25 12:25:00 UTC |        ... |  0 |                           3 |
| user1@gmail.com   | 2020-06-26 15:21:00 UTC |        ... |  2 |                           2 |
| user2@hotmail.com | 2020-06-21 12:23:00 UTC |        ... |  0 |                           1 |
| user2@hotmail.com | 2020-06-21 16:54:00 UTC |        ... |  0 |                           1 |
| user2@hotmail.com | 2020-06-22 08:23:00 UTC |        ... |  0 |                           1 |
| user2@hotmail.com | 2020-06-22 12:13:00 UTC |        ... |  1 |                           2 |
| user2@hotmail.com | 2020-06-24 09:32:00 UTC |        ... |  1 |                           2 |
| user2@hotmail.com | 2020-06-25 05:45:00 UTC |        ... |  1 |                           2 |
| user2@hotmail.com | 2020-06-26 12:32:00 UTC |        ... |  1 |                           1 |
| user2@hotmail.com | 2020-06-27 19:53:00 UTC |        ... |  1 |                           1 |
+-------------------+-------------------------+------------+----+-----------------------------+
```

I have tried using a window function to partition by email and count distinct ids over the preceding 3 days.

```
COUNT(DISTINCT id) OVER (PARTITION BY email ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d', day))*24*3600 RANGE BETWEEN 3*24*3600 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
```

However this is not allowed:

```
Window ORDER BY is not allowed if DISTINCT is specified
```

There are solutions on stack overflow, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35174397/google-bigquery-rolling-count-distinct). However I'm not certain that it accounts for the need to partition by email before counting unique ids.

I'd be grateful for any pointers on this. If it's easier, I'd also be open to a solution that uses DATE rather than TIMESTAMP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT(ids),
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM t.ids AS id) distinct_ids
FROM (
  SELECT *, ARRAY_AGG(id) OVER(preceding_days) ids
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  WINDOW preceding_days AS (
    PARTITION BY email 
    ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(DATE(day)) 
    ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
  )
) t
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'user1@gmail.com' email, TIMESTAMP'2020-06-21 16:31:00 UTC' day, '...' other_cols, 0 id UNION ALL
  SELECT 'user1@gmail.com', '2020-06-22 14:54:00 UTC', '...', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'user1@gmail.com', '2020-06-23 08:23:00 UTC', '...', 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'user1@gmail.com', '2020-06-24 13:51:00 UTC', '...', 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'user1@gmail.com', '2020-06-25 09:54:00 UTC', '...', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'user1@gmail.com', '2020-06-25 12:25:00 UTC', '...', 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'user1@gmail.com', '2020-06-26 15:21:00 UTC', '...', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'user2@hotmail.com', '2020-06-21 12:23:00 UTC', '...', 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'user2@hotmail.com', '2020-06-21 16:54:00 UTC', '...', 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'user2@hotmail.com', '2020-06-22 08:23:00 UTC', '...', 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'user2@hotmail.com', '2020-06-22 12:13:00 UTC', '...', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'user2@hotmail.com', '2020-06-24 09:32:00 UTC', '...', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'user2@hotmail.com', '2020-06-25 05:45:00 UTC', '...', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'user2@hotmail.com', '2020-06-26 12:32:00 UTC', '...', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'user2@hotmail.com', '2020-06-27 19:53:00 UTC', '...', 1 
)
SELECT * EXCEPT(ids),
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM t.ids AS id) distinct_ids
FROM (
  SELECT *, ARRAY_AGG(id) OVER(preceding_days) ids
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  WINDOW preceding_days AS (
    PARTITION BY email 
    ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(DATE(day)) 
    ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
  )
) t
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved the question. The only change I made was to use UNIX_SECONDS so that ids on the same day, but seen at a later time weren't counted. Admittedly that wasn't what I asked for in the question!

ORDER BY UNIX_SECONDS(EnquiryDateTime) RANGE BETWEEN 187200 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW

Answer (score 4):

Most (if not all) databases do not support `distinct` in window functions. In BigQuery, you would typically work around this using a window string or arrays aggregation:

```
select 
    t.* except(ids),
    (select count(distinct id) from unnest(split(ids)) as id) cnt_distinct_id
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        string_agg(id) over(
            partition by email 
            order by unix_date(parse_date('%y-%m-%d', day))*24*3600 
            range between 3 * 24 * 3600 preceding and current row 
        ) ids
    from mytable t
) t
```

The subquery aggregates all `id`s over the three preceding days in a string, using `string_agg()` as a window function; then, the outer query splits and unnest the string, and counts the distinct `id`s.