# Cumulative Count with DISTINCT function in Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'd like to add 'cumulative_cnt' column by counting distinct ad_id cumulatively every day - however in Google BigQuery, the COUNT(DISTINCT) function within window functions was not supported in BigQuery. I'd like to discover the alternative way.

```
    SELECT date(parse_datetime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S', login_datetime)) as login_start_dt, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT (ad_id)) as cnt COUNT(DISTINCT (ad_id)) OVER ( ORDER BY date(parse_datetime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S', login_datetime)) ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) as cumulative_cnt
    FROM `export.table'
    WHERE (length(login_datetime) = 14) AND (date(parse_datetime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S', login_datetime)) \< CURRENT_DATE())
    GROUP BY login_start_dt
    ORDER BY login_start_dt DESC
```

Asked to Chat GPT for modifying the code but it doesn't work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63158386/bigquery-distinct-count-in-rolling-date-range-with-partition-on-column?rq=2  might be helpful.