# Rolling count daily active drivers since beginning

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery

I have a list of drivers, orders, and dates in a table named `all_data` between 2022-01-01 and 2022-01-15 (15 days) like this:

| driver_id | order_id | order_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 2022-01-01 |
| 1 | b | 2022-01-02 |
| 2 | c | 2022-01-01 |
| 2 | d | 2022-01-03 |

For all 15 days, how do I find the number of continually active drivers, who completed at least one order every single day, up to that date? The output should be a table like this:

| order_date | active_drivers |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 30 |
| 2022-01-02 | 27 |
| 2022-01-03 | 25 |

For example, on 2022-01-01, there were 30 unique drivers who completed at least one order that day. On 2022-01-02, we must find the number of unique drivers who completed at least one order on 2022-01-01 and 2022-01-02. On 2022-01-03, we must count drivers who completed at least one order on 2022-01-01, 2022-01-02, and 2022-01-03.

**What I have tried**

I found a similar solution in MySQL (below) but it is not allowed in bigquery because of the error "Unsupported subquery with table in join predicate".

```
MySQL
SELECT order_date, 
 (SELECT COUNT(distinct s1.driver_id) as num_hackers 
   FROM all_data s2 
   join all_data s1 
   on s2. order_date = s1. order_date and     
     (SELECT COUNT(distinct s3. order_date) 
      FROM all_data s3 
      WHERE s3.driver_id = s2.driver_id 
        AND s3. order_date < s1. order_date) 
     = datediff(s1. order_date, date('2022-01-01'), day)
))
from all_data
```

I also read this [Google BigQuery: Rolling Count Distinct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35174397/google-bigquery-rolling-count-distinct) question but that is for a fixed 45 number of days, while the number of days here is a variable based on the date. How do I write a query in BigQuerySQL to find the rolling number of continually active drivers per day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below

```
select order_date, count(distinct if(flag, driver_id, null)) active_drivers
from (
  select order_date, driver_id, 
    row_number() over(partition by driver_id order by order_date) - 
    date_diff(order_date, min(order_date) over(), day) = 1 as flag
  from (select distinct order_date, driver_id from all_data)
)
group by order_date
```

Answer (score 0):

First find out all combination of dates and drivers, then just get count of all drivers per date. Try this:

```
select order_date, count(*)
from(
    select order_date, driver_id, count(*)
    from all_data ad
    group by order_date, driver_id)
group by order_date
```

Comment: Thanks but that's not correct. This is about finding how many unique drivers per rolling day (including previous days), not how many orders per driver per day. The drivers also have to be active on the previous consecutive days.